# SQL Server functions and WHERE

Tags: sql-server, function, view

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and I find myself reusing the following functions to find the first day of the last month and the first day of this month:

```sql
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

While creating a function with a name like `firstDayLastMonth`, for example, is almost as long, it's definitely more readable and merely glancing at the scalar function name clues me in on what's going on.

As I understand it, I shouldn't use user defined functions like the above in a WHERE clause (possible, or even likely bad performance). But as I am creating Views in SQL Server, that's where I continue to reuse the two code snippets above to calculate the date range of the first of last month to the first of this month. Is there still a way to create a function, or something similar, so that my date ranges are actually readable at a glance?

Comment: Have you tried EOMonth() and/or DateFromParts()  ?

Comment: You can use an Inline Table Valued Function to gain the benefits of a function without the performance loss of a Scalar Function.

Comment: I think performance wouldn't be much of an issue unless you're dealing with huge data sets. A simple scalar function would be my approach, but again, depends on size of your data.

Comment: The data I'm working with is quite large so I'm sure at some point I'd see the performance loss.

I'll look into the inline Table Value Function. Thanks Dale!